# Listen to HTML/CSS events of web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, objective-c, css

I'm looking for a way to listen for an event in the HTML/CSS of a webpage. Basically, a website I use at work lists queues and appointments, which flag as yellow/red based on the amount of time late on taking said appointment. Other than this visual aide, there is no alert of any kind, which is a failing point if one is juggling multiple windows and doesn't notice.

What I would like to do is put together a simple way to watch for the tag ID or perhaps the flag hex color, and then alert me in a way of my choosing.

The work environment is on OS X, so I presume I'm looking at an Objective-C centric solution unless Applescript is capable of doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is doable but tricky, and subject to breaking if the site changes its structure. You have no way of influencing the web site to do the output for you? It does not offer an RSS feed, which would be much easier to monitor?

Comment: There have been several revisions and updates with no change to the tags and hex color, so I'm not concerned. The site is not enabled with any feed or monitor, however due to server strain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you didn't tag jQuery, or JavaScript, but a custom bookmarklet may be the solution.

As it so happens I created a [bookmarklet utility](http://zbooks.zzzzbov.com/) a while back so that you can keep your bookmarklet in an external script file.

You could then have `alert` or `confirm` called automatically for some event on the page.

Comment: A question, though. Would this bookmarklet be able to only do visual, or also perform an audible alert? Also, would be it restricted to the browser, or visible on another webpage?

Comment: You can make a bookmarklet do just about anything you want. It's just a javascript function run from your favorites bar. So that's a yes to an audio alert.

Comment: @David Metcalfe you wont necessarily be able to make it visible on another webpage, but alerts/confirms may interrupt other pages (depending on the browser). As far as audio is concerned: bookmarklets have the advantage of not needing to be cross-browser compliant as you're making it for yourself. If you use a good browser (not IE), you can use HTML5 <audio> easily.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to specify the browser your users use?  If so, Chrome has support for HTML5's out of browser notifications, ala: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#notifications-api

Comment: Downright gorgeous. But the Mac environment we have is given with little permission to deviate from stock setup. Safari is all we have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a reference to the dom elements you want to monitor, and use `setInterval()` to poll the data you are looking for on some interval, alerting when it changes.

[See this fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/EtkKx/) for an example.